# Unable to add properties in a MongoDB document

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, authentication, mern

I am trying to implement password reset functionality in a MERN application. Whenever a user enters their email (for which they want to reset the password) and clicks on the "Send Password Reset Link" button, a POST request is made to the route "/account/forgot".

In the route handler function, I check whether any user with the given email exists or not. If a user exists, then I add resetPasswordLink and resetPasswordExpires properties to the user object and send a message "You have been emailed a password link" to the client.

The problem I am facing is I get the message at the frontend.
[image]

**However, whenever I check the database, I don't see resetPasswordLink and resetPassworExpires properties being added to the user.**

[image]

Where is the problem?

The code snippets are given below:

server/routes/passwordResetRoutes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const User = require("../models/userModel");

const router = express.Router();

router.post(
  "/forgot",
  asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

    if (user) {
      user.passwordResetToken = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString("hex");
      user.passwordResetExpires = Date.now() + 3600000;
      await user.save();

      res.json({
        message: "You have been emailed a password reset link",
      });
    } else {
      const err = new Error("No account with that email exists");
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    }
  })
);

module.exports = router;
```

server/models/userModel.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  resetPasswordToken: {
    type: String,
  },
  resetPasswordExpires: {
    type: Date,
  },
});

userSchema.methods.matchPassword = async function (incomingPassword) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(incomingPassword, this.password);
};

userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to update the `passwordResetToken` and `passwordResetExpires` fields but they are not present in the `User` model. That's why the `user.save()` call does nothing. They should be `resetPasswordToken` and `resetPasswordExpires` respectively.

```
user.resetPasswordToken = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex')
user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000
await user.save()
```